# I can’t install ionic on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

My Versions are :

- Node version is v0.10.33
- npm version is 1.4.28
- Cordova version is 5.0.0

**The error that occurred when I installed ionic:**

```
**jce010:~ Tareqalmasri$ sudo npm install -g ionic**
Password:
/
> node-sass@0.9.6 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node build.js

`darwin-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing


  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․

  26 passing (51ms)

Binary is fine; exiting
ionic@1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
├── gulp-concat@2.5.2 (through2@0.6.5, gulp-util@3.0.5, concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.2)
├── gulp@3.8.11 (pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, interpret@0.3.10, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@1.0.0, minimist@1.1.1, v8flags@2.0.5, tildify@1.0.0, semver@4.3.6, chalk@0.5.1, orchestrator@0.3.7, liftoff@2.1.0, gulp-util@3.0.5, vinyl-fs@0.3.13)
├── gulp-minify-css@0.3.13 (memory-cache@0.0.5, through2@0.6.5, vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4, bufferstreams@0.0.2, clean-css@3.0.10, gulp-util@3.0.5)
└── gulp-sass@0.7.3 (map-stream@0.1.0, gulp-util@3.0.5, node-sass@0.9.6)
```

When I type ionic -v, I get

```
jce010:~ Tareqalmasri$ ionic -v 
-bash: ionic: command not found
```

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I'd imagine this is a path issue. Can you see if /usr/local/bin is added to your PATH and that /usr/local/bin/ionic binary exists?

Comment: The /usr/local/bin is added to my PATH. But the /usr/local/bin/ionic binary  is NOT exist in my PATH or device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution :) .

The solution is apply the following command:

> sudo npm update -g cordova ionic

Answer (score 0):

**Homebrew solved it in my case**

It took me hours to install ionic, frustrating especially on a very sunny day >(

Nothing worked:

- bash profile entries
- sudo commands
- npm updates
- etc

What finally solved everything: I installed node using "***Homebrew***". After that all commands worked perfectly:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic start myApp tabs
```